# Foursquare API Limiting to the city

Tags: api, foursquare

I am working with Foursquare api. Trying to find grocery stores/Supermarkets in the city of Norfolk, VA. When I do the search on foursquare.com, I get 30 in the city. When I use the API, it gives me 11, and a bunch of stores in surrounding cities.

I think the stores in the nearby cities eat into my limit of 50.

I've tried using both the "near" tag and the "ll" tag.

Is there a way to limit the search to just the specific city?

Comment: Which API do you use? e.g. search, explore

Comment: I have tried both. But I've primarily been focused on search.  https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&oauth_token={}&&v={}&near={}&categoryId={}